# selectrow at index for different sections

Tags: ios, swift, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a table with two sections.  I can select row at index - but I cannot differentiate between the sections.

the table is a pullout menu - which is created solely in code.

the delegate method for the selection is

```
func sideBarControlDidSelectRow(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    delegate?.sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    sectionis = indexPath.section
    NSLog("Index Path Section %d", indexPath.section)
}
```

this gives me the section in the console.

but on the view controller all I have is

```
func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index: Int){
    switch(index) {
        etc.
    }
}
```

What I need to be able to do is something like

```
func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index: Int){
    if section == 0 {
        switch(index){
            etc.
        }
    }
}
```

but if I try that then Binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type section

this has got to be something obvious as tables have sections all the time  - but the answer is eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update declaration of method `sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex` in delegate protocol to accept NSIndexPath value, change:

```
func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index: Int)
```

to

```
func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

then you can just remove this method

```
func sideBarControlDidSelectRow(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    delegate?.sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(indexPath.row)
}
```

and replace its call just with

```
delegate?.sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(indexPath)
```

Then you'll receive full indexPath and could do what you want

Comment: So easy  when you know how.